# NetBeans has broken interface with OpenJDK

Tags: java, openjdk, netbeans, jdk, mint

Sorry for English.

Usually (say, at 4/5 of times), when I start NetBeans, interface is partially broken. For example, menu items are appearing and at once disappearing after click; some parts of editor are also blocked for cursor actions. Another issue is broken Options window - I can show it only once for NetBeans execution. There are more similar issues.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Version of NetBeans is 7.0.1.
Linux version is Mint 16. I use Mate. I had the same issue at other computer, at the same operating  system.

I know that installing Sun version of Java could help, but I also know that there shouldn't be such issue with OpenJDK. Also, I had other problem with NetBeans and Sun Java 8 - NetBeans suddenly crashed before he fully started, so I want to stick with OpenJDK.

What causes my problem? Should I use other version of NetBeans/OpenJDK?

Comment: So you want *menu items* to stay even after you click on it?

Comment: I don't know if I used correct word, but I don't know other. Menu items = File, Edit, View etc. They should stay after one click, this is normal behaviour. @Naveen

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. netbeans interface was distorted.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

after :

```
:/opt$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

netbeans returned to work.

Answer (score 0):

"I had the same issue at other computer, at the same operating system."
so the os seems to be the issue, because it is very unlikely the be jdk ot netbeans problem. but you can try to install netbeans 8